# Remove an specific user from Room in EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have a room including some users. I want to remove an specific user from the room.

Here are my Models:

```
public class RoomModel
{
    [Required]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Admin { get; set; }
    public ICollection<UserModel> Users { get; set; }
}

public class UserModel
{
    [Key]
    public string UserID { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

And my database context:

```
 public class DBContext :  IdentityDbContext
    {

        public DBContext() 
        {

        }

        public DBContext(DbContextOptions<DBContext> options) : base(options)
        {

        }

        public DbSet<RoomModel> Rooms { get; set; }
        public DbSet<UserModel> Users { get; set; }
 }
```

How can I remove an specific user from the room and save changes in database?

Comment: Specify the exact version of EF Core.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since in your `UserModel` enity there is no CLR property which holds the foreign key for the relationship, a shadow property `RoomModelId` is created.

See the documentation for more information: [Shadow and Indexer Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/shadow-properties).

We can use this shadow property to efficiently perform the deletion without making unnecessary queries to the database.

```
// We get the room somehow.
var room = db.Rooms.First(r => r.Name == "room A");

// Create a user with the desired id.
var user = new UserModel { UserID = "x" };
// Or we get a user from the database. But this is an unnecessary query.
//var user = db.Users.First(u => u.UserID == "x");

// Set the foreign key value to the shadow property.
db.Entry(user).Property("RoomModelId").CurrentValue = room.Id;

// Mark entity as deleted.
db.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Deleted;

db.SaveChanges();
```

---

I would add the following properties to the `UserModel`, for more convenience:

```
public int RoomModelId { get; set; }
public RoomModel Room { get; set; }
```

Comment: In above example do you think you need to attach the entity (user) before changing the state and saving to database? I believe that is because entity user is not loaded yet and you cant get/set `CurrentValue` of a detached  object.

Comment: @sairfan - This is a fully working example, proven in practice. See [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.entry?view=efcore-6.0). Quote: "This method may be called on an entity that is not tracked. You can then set the State property on the returned entry to have the context begin tracking the entity in the specified state".

Comment: I already +1 for you, as I like your code and approach.  I asked this question because, in past it did not work for me and I wanted to learn.  there must be some update on this.

Answer (score 1):

Load rooms with navigation property Users, then find the user to remove.

```
 var userId = "1234-ABC";

 // Eager loading
 var rooms = db.Rooms
               .Include(u => u.Users)
               .ToList();
 // or Explicit loading
 // var rooms = db.Rooms.Collection(u => u.Users).Load();

 var user = rooms.Users.Where(u => u.UserId == userId).FirstOrDefault();
 rooms.Users.Remove(user);  // should check if user is not null
 // now you can save changes to db
 db.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you should configure the relationship between the `RoomModel` and `UserModel`. To configure the relationship, use the `ForeignKey` attribute in `UserModel`:

```
public class UserModel
{
    [Key]
    public string UserID { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    // foreign key
    public string RoomId{ get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("RoomId")]
    public RoomModel Room{ get; set; }
}
```

To remove the user from Room1:

```
private void RemoveUser(string userId)
{
    var room = _db.Rooms.Where(s => s.Name == "Room1")
               .Include(s => s.Users).FirstOrDefault();
    var user = room.Users.Where(u => u.UserID == userId).FirstOrDefault();

    room.Users.Remove(user);
    _db.SaveChanges();
}
```